# SELECT - Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select

Does anyone know another way to run the query below more efficiently? I'm using SQL Server 2014.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(1) VolumeTransacaoBoleto
     FROM 
         TableA WITH (NOLOCK)--orders WITH(NOLOCK) 
     WHERE 
         TIT_DATA_EMISSAO BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-02'
    ) Amount1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) VolumeRegistro     
     FROM TableB WITH (NOLOCK)
     WHERE payment_type IN (300, -1)
       AND data BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-02') Amount2
```

I'm aware that using subqueries is not best way to do this. I would like to show all counts separately by column.

This is the execution plan, after that I created an index on `TableB` like @Ezlo said

[image]

Comment: Schema / Index information would be useful

Comment: Since you have filter on dates, you can define partition on date column of both tables. It will help improve performance.

Comment: ok , i'll post all evidences out here . And about structure .. its ok to do Subqueries ?

Comment: @GauravS no it won't. Partitions aren't meant to improve query performance, in fact they typically *harm* it. It's indexes that are important

Comment: @Luiz forget about evidence. Post the table schema,  indexes and execution plan. Remove the `NOLOCK` hints too. They mean "read dirty data while taking big locks". If you felt the need to add them it means you are trying to read too much data from a table used by others

Comment: @Luiz btw the query you posted is bad. It's actually *two* separate queries, which will become evident once you check the execution plan. Hit Ctrl+L in SSMS. Do you have indexes on the `TIT_DATA_EMISSAO`, `payment_type` and `data` fields? Are the `TIT_DATA_EMISSAO` and `data` fields actually dates or strings?

Comment: @Luiz finally, you can improve performance over well-indexed tables by 100x times or more if you use Columnstore indexes. The data is stored *and* compressed in column format. Instead of scanning multiple rows to calculate counts, the server only checks how many individual column value combinations there are for `paymenttype` and `date` (a very rough description). They are available in all versions and editions since 2016 SP1

Comment: Actually i did what Ezlo said and i got a huge perfomance on it . Actually i know theres another wayt to do this , i mean .. avoid using subqueries

Comment: @Luiz that wouldn't help. What you posted isn't two subqueries, it's two individual queries in the same statement. If you execute them individually you'll get the same performance. It's *indexing* that's important. In *all* databases, performance is provided by the indexes. Without them the database has to scan *all* data to find matching records. Columnstores essentially index and compress everything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you have a STEP-BY-STEP to re-create all index on my databases ,following best practices to create them ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:- Indexes are more helpful in joins and filtering but  partitions are equally helpful in improving performance. Once you define partition on a column, DB will query only partition mentioned in where clause and will not do a full table scan. Refer to link for more details.   https://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/sql-indexes/partitioning-benefits

Comment: When the parameters (they are not constant as you showed I think) are of type date\time, then SQL server seems to have problems with that. Probably you would need to add option(recompile) to your query. Recompilation takes milliseconds for a query like this. Unfortunately I don't know of a code to show the problem, it is not reproducible always. Almost all the time when experienced it, it boiled down to recompile (despite having indexes).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Which cases i got to use Recompile ?

Comment: As I said I experienced it when the query contains date\datetime parameters in where clause. Even when the indexes exists, one query returning 100 rows might be running much slower than a query returning thousands of rows. No consistent pattern I could see to solve. I suggest you add option (recompile) to the query you shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 specific indexes for your query, as the following ones:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TableAIndex ON TableA (TIT_DATA_EMISSAO)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TableBIndex ON TableB (payment_type, data)
```

If you can make them `CLUSTERED` then better (you will have to drop your already existing clustered index first, or primary key if it's also clustered).

Also make sure that `TIT_DATA_EMISSAO` and `data` are `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type.